# Getter method returns null. Java MVC

Tags: java, mysql, swing, model-view-controller, methods

I have googled for a whole day but I just can't find an answer to my problem.

I'm using the MVC pattern.
Basically I have a list of songs (id, title, author, ect.) that I need to display in a `JTable`. The songs are stored in a MySQL database.The Connection to database works fine.

I'm currently storing all the reconds from my database in an 'ArrayList'

**This is what I have so far:**

The code to store the songs:

```
SongDAO songDAO = new SongDAO();
ArrayList<Song> songs = songDAO.findAll();
```

When printing out the songs, I get this output:

```
[oop.model.entities.Song@1055e4af, oop.model.entities.Song@3caeaf62, oop.model.entities.Song@e6ea0c6, oop.model.entities.Song@6a38e57f]
```

This is where I play the first song:

```
if (songs.isEmpty()) {
    library = null; 
} else {
    library = songs.get(0);
    Mainframe.setVisible(true);
    firstController();
}

public static Library getLibrary() {
    return library; 
}
```

The library static factory method:

```
public static void firstController() {
    new libraryController(view.libraryView);
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is here. I just can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
public class libraryController {
   private libraryView view;

   public libraryController(libraryView view) {
       this.view = view;
        for (Song song : baseController.getLibrary().getSongs()) {
            view.addSong(song);
        }
        updateView();
    }

    public void updateView() {
        view.setSongs(baseController.getLibrary().getSongs());
    }
}
```

I've tried `System.out.println(baseController.getLibrary().getSongs())`, but all i get is `[ ]`. This leads me to believe the `getSongs()` method is the cause.

```
public void setSongs(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
    for (Song song : songs) {
        addSong(Song);
    }
}

public void addSong(Song song) {
    Object[] row = new Object[]{song.getId(), song.getTitle(), song.getArtist(), song.getAlbum(), song.getGenre(), song.getYear()};
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Here is my Library Class:

```
public class Library {
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private int id;
    private Song song;

    public Library() {
        id=0;
        songs = new ArrayList<Song>(20);
    }

    public ArrayList<Song> getSongs() {
        return songs;
    }

    public Libreria setSongs(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
        this.songs = songs;
        return this;
    }
}
```

My song class:

```
public class Song extends Library {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String album;
    private String genre;
    private int year;
    private Library library;

    public Song(){
        id = 0;
    } 

    public int getId() {return id; }

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getTitle() { return title;}

    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public String getArtist() { return artist;}

    public void setArtist(String artist) {this.artist = artist;}

    public String getAlbum() {return album;}

    public void setAlbum(String album) {this.album = album; }

    public String getGenre() {return genre;}

    public void setGenre(String genre) {this.genre = genre;}

    public int getYear() {return year;}

    public void setYear(int year) {this.year = year;}

    public Library getLibrary() {return library;}

    public Song setLibrary(Library library) {
        this.library = library;
        return this;
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When calling `setSongs(ArrayList<Song> songs)` does the ArrayList have content?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen No, i've tried to do a System.out.println(songs) inside setSongs(ArrayList<Song> songs) and gives me [ ].

Comment: SO we can safely state that `ArrayList<Song> songs = songDAO.findAll();` is not working. Can you add that part (and maybe reduce the rest of your question a bit for readability)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically i have to display in JTable my songs ('id','title,'author','..')

Swing components are already designed using a modified version of MVC.

If you want to display data in a JTable you just need to load the data into a TableModel.

So you may want to create a custom TableModel so hold your Song objects.

Check out [Table Row Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/).

It shows you step by step how to create a custom model for the Song object. Or if you want you can use the generic `TableRowModel` to make the coding easier.

Once you create the SongTableModel the code to use it would be something like:

```
SongTableModel model = new SongTableModel( songs );
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Comment: thanks for help but this isn't the problem.. i have already a costum TableModel. My main problem is that i cant pass songs to Arraylist<Song>..

Comment: @LucaPetrovic, You stated your DB connection is fine which means you should be able to load the data into your ArrayList and then you should be able to create your custom TableModel and the JTable. All your other classes like Libarary are not needed because  all the data will be stored in the TableModel so it effectively becomes the "Library".  If you ever want to access the data you should only ever be accessing the data via the TableModel methods NEVER through the ArrayList directly.